# Is there any parking in Guatemala near border with Honduras (near Copan Ruinas)?

Tags: safety, borders, automobiles, guatemala, honduras

Is it possible safely leave a rented car in Guatemala near border with Honduras (near Copan Ruinas) for one night?
Thank you.